# Unable to pause/forward/backward video using mediacontroller in android

Tags: android, android-videoview, mediacontroller

Iam unable to **pause / forward / backward** the video using **MediaController** and it is happening  only in the LG devices. Below is the code which am using and it is working in the rest of all the devices :

```
    VideoView video=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.video);
    MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(video);
    video.setMediaController(mediaController);
    video.setVideoURI(uri);
    video.start();
```

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found a solution...

In some LG devices, by defaultly controls are disabled in VideoView.

So we have to explicitly enable them by Overriding the below functions in VideoView:

```
@Override
public boolean canSeekForward() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean canSeekBackward() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean canPause() {
    return true;
}
```